# get json string at server side in php-wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

hy,i am working on a wordpress plugin in which i require to delete multiple items using checkbox.when i check all rows and delete them i get their row id in the form of json string.
js code:

```
$('.check_it:checked').each(function (i){
                            c[i]=$(this).val();                         
                        });         

                        var chk = JSON.stringify({ list: c });
                        debugger

                        $.ajax({
                                        type:"POST",
                                        data: chk,
                                        url:'/word/wp-content/plugins/craiglist/action.php?action=delete_leads',
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        success:function(response){
                                                            alert('fdsfsfdsfd');                    
                                            },  
                                        failure:function (response) {
                                                alert("Please Try Again");
                                            },
                                        error:function (xhr, status, error) {

                                                alert(xhr.response);           
                                            }
                                    });
```

In var chk i got string like

```
"{"list":["151","152","153","154","155","156","157","158","159","160","161","162","163","164","165","166","167","168","169","170","171","172","173","174","175"]}"
```

how can i get it at server side in php and send it to database so i can delete the so called rows.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are sending JSON as the post data, you will have to access the raw post data on the PHP side. This can be done like so:

```
$obj = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
foreach($obj->list as $item)
{
    // delete from mytable
    $wpdb->query( 
        $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = %d", $item)
    );
}
```

---

If you want the data in a `$_POST` variable, then you will have to change your ajax request data to something like:

```
$.ajax({
    ....
    data: { list : JSON.stringify(c) },
    ....
```

Now, on the PHP side it is present in `$_POST['list']`. So you can do:

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST['list']);
foreach($obj->list as $item)
{
    // delete from mytable
    $wpdb->query( 
        $wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM mytable WHERE id = %d", $item)
    );
}
```

Comment: how can i get it on server side means $_POST['list']; or something else.

Comment: it gives undefined in $obj

Comment: What is in `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`? Try my second method to use `$_POST['list']`. IRRC you might have to `stripslashes()` with wordpress user input.

Comment: `global $wpdb;
   $lead_id=json_decode($_POST['list'],true);
   var_dump($lead_id);
   foreach($lead_id->list as $lead_id1)
   {
    $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM tbl_leads WHERE id = %d", $lead_id1));
    echo "Leads Deleted Successfully . . !!";
   }`  it is my server side code to delete items.

Answer (score 0):

In your server side php since you're not calling the get_header() function, you have to add this piece of code manually `require_once('../../../wp-load.php');` and you can now call global $wpdb; safely and all wp functions. Please also take note that you're php file must be inside your theme together with your functions.php and other core files. **Do not put it into another directory inside your theme**